# WebClient async stuck

Tags: c#, asynchronous, webclient

I have this code:

```
autoResetEvent = new AutoResetEvent(false);
clien = new WebClient();
clien.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
clien.DownloadDataCompleted += new DownloadDataCompletedEventHandler(clien_DownloadDataCompleted);
clien.DownloadDataAsync(new Uri("http://www.classoneequipment.com/"));
autoResetEvent.WaitOne();

void clien_DownloadDataCompleted(object sender, DownloadDataCompletedEventArgs e)
 {
        Encoding enc = Encoding.UTF8;
        myString = enc.GetString(e.Result);
        autoResetEvent.Set();
 }
```

When I run this code in a button click event - It works fine. but when I run the code from big class it gets stucked and don't arrive to the func: clien_DownloadDataCompleted.

Comment: ***WHY*** do you use the async version when you wait for completion? And how do the callback access the `autoResetEvent`?

Comment: @jgauffin, I use async because it is the fastest. and I update my code

Comment: Async is not (noticeably) faster or slower than a synchronous method. The IO is the bottleneck.

Comment: Your code is not thread safe, kind of ironic ;) (since using the sync `DownloadString` inside your method would make it thread safe). And as @CodeCaster said: There will not be any performance increase since the time it takes talking to the server is several times larger then the actual method invocation. this is a prime example of premature optimization which also produces less readable code.

Comment: @CodeCaster, I didn't understand your answer, how can it be that async is not faser, so why use async?

Comment: @jgauffin, but in my code on my proggram all this code in loop (Parallel.Loop) because I downnload 3,000 or more pages, so it is better to use in async.

Comment: @Chanipoz drop the idea that async was made to make things faster. That is not its goal.

Comment: @Chanipoz a definition I stole from a result found when searching _"why use asynchronous methods"_: _"A synchronous method call waits for the method to complete before continuing with program flow, whereas an asynchronous method call will return immediately so that the program can perform other operations while the called method completes its work."_

Answer (score 3):

You approach it all wrong. If you want to download 3000 or more pages you got to be a bit more efficient and not wait on the event from each download.

Implementation (just a rough draft, you have to complete it)

```
public class Downloader
{
    ConcurrentQueue<Uri> _queue = new ConcurrentQueue<Uri>();
    int _maxWorkers = 10;
    long _currentWorkers = 0;
    ManualResetEvent _completed;

    public void Enqueue(Uri uri)
    {
        _queue.Enqueue(uri);
        if (Interlocked.Read(_currentWorkers)  < _maxWorkers)
        {
            // not very thread safe, but we just want to limit the workers
            // within a reasonable limit. 1 or 2 more doesn't really matter.
            Interlocked.Increment(_currentWorkers);

            // yes, i'm a bit old fashioned.
            TriggerJob();
        }
    }

    private void TriggerJob()
    {
        Uri uri;
        if (!_queue.TryDequeue(out uri))
        {
            Interlocked.Decrement(_currentWorkers);
            return;
        }

        var client = new WebClient();
        client.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
        client.DownloadDataCompleted += DownloadDataCompleted;
        client.DownloadDataAsync(uri);
    }

    private void DownloadDataCallback(object sender, DownloadDataCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            // If the request was not canceled and did not throw 
            // an exception, display the resource. 
            if (!e.Cancelled && e.Error == null)
            {
                var args = new DownloadedEventArgs { uri = e.Uri, data = (byte[])e.result};
                DownloadCompleted(this, args)
            }
            else
            {
                var args = new DownloadFailedEventArgs { uri = e.Uri, error = e.Error };
                DownloadFailed(this, args);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception err)
        {
            var args = new DownloadFailedEventArgs { uri = e.Uri, error = err };
            DownloadFailed(this, args);
        }

        TriggerJob();
    }

    public event EventHandler<DownloadedEventArgs> DownloadCompleted = delegate{};
    public event EventHandler<DownloadFailedEventArgs> DownloadFailed = delegate{};

}


public class DownloadedEventArgs
{
    public Uri uri;
    public byte[] data;
}

public class DownloadFailedEventArgs
{
    public Uri uri;
    public Exception error;
}
```

Usage:

```
var downloader = new Downloader();
downloader.Completed += (o,e) { Console.WriteLine("Whoohoho, completed: " + e.Uri); };

for (x = 1; x < 100000; x++)
{
    downloader.Enqueue(new Uri("http://somewhere.com));
}
```

Comment: @jgauffin, You wrote: "downloader.Completed" there is no func with the name "Completed"

Comment: there are errors in the code. I just typed it directly in the answer box. giving you a fully working code will just make you use it without understanding it. Study the code and you'll see what the event is called.

Comment: @jgauffin, thanks, but although I studied the code, and changed it to match me, I do not understand all the code, and don't understand what event is it.

Comment: There are only two events declared in the downloader. you have 50% to get it right ;) hint: Events have the `event` keyword in the declaration

Comment: @jgauffin, the declaration of the `event` alert an error because of `{}`

Comment: Sorry, typo. fixed. Using an empty delegate on the event declarations make it possible to always invoke them, no matter if there are any other subscribers or not.